# multiply an image array with a scalar value in opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, multiplication

I am trying to multiply an image by a scalar value in python OpenCV, but could not get any output. Here is my code:

```
img=cv2.imread('pepper.png',0)
img1=img*1.2            
cv2.imshow('image',img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

When you multiply by a scalar value that is not an integer, you need to set the image back to `uint8` format. So try

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('pepper.png',0)
img1=img*1.2
img1=img1.astype('uint8')           
cv2.imshow("image", img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also be sure the window containing the displayed image is not underneath other windows.

Comment: If that was an acceptable answer, please consider giving it an up-vote.